# Is it possible to access the value of data-* on the server side?

Tags: javascript, html, express, server, pug

I'm quite new to the whole web dev, so please if the following approach seems irrational please enlighten me.

What I'm trying to do is, to store an object (in my case logged in user) on form element and then be able to somehow retrieve the value (when the form submits) on the server side and push it to an array of a database model (mongoose).

The problem I'm encountering is with the "retrieving" part. My current implementation looks like this:

Jade/HTML:

```
form(action="/api/addUserRequest" method="post")             
  input(type="text" name="user_data" data-currentUser= currentUser)
  input(type="submit" value="Submit")
```

As you can see, I'm storing the currently logged in user in data-attribute (This seems to output correct object if console.logged in the browser). How would I then go about retrieving this value inside my express app? I'm just clueless, any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add hidden input like this (in your notation type):

```
form(action="/api/addUserRequest" method="post") 
  input(type="hidden" name="user_profile" value= currentUser)            
  input(type="text" name="user_data")
  input(type="submit" value="Submit")
```

Then on server side it will be available as a part of POSTed data.

Comment: I am currently looping through a list of game_instances objects, each object contains a name and id amongst other properties. Upon clicking on a button I'm sending the object of user_data and also trying to store the looped object in another input field named "game_instance". When sending through the form, and consoling it out, I get "[object Object]". I cannot get it to work, so I can access the properties of that looped object if that makes sense.

Comment: I think that you might be trying to console.log('somestring '+yourDataObject) - this way in console you will always get output similar to this - 'somestring [object Object]'. Try to console.log(yourDataObject)!

Comment: I'm using the direct body object from req.body like so: `console.log(req.body.game_instance)` and in the console I get that `[object Object]` I thought maybe it's how it is in the console but when I try to access its properties it's saying "undefined". Is it possible for the object to be empty?

Comment: And what is the output console.log(typeof req.body.game_instance)?

Comment: Oh, i again reread your initial question: "Upon clicking on a button I'm sending the object of user_data and also trying to store the looped object in another input field named "game_instance". When sending through the form, and consoling it out, I get "[object Object]"... Please double check the html after you "trying to store the looped object in another input field named "game_instance". TLDR: You cannot store object in plain html directly...

Comment: If there`s an ultimate need in storing it inside input field value - you should convert it to json. But it is not cool and not recommended - you can just do it without modification of html by directly injecting it to your ajax request. Just google for JSON.stringify...

Comment: The type of `req.body.game_instance` is string. So that explains why I cannot use "dot notation" to access its properties. How would I then be able to pass an object via the form? I'll just reiterate, I want to be able to pass an object through the form post request and access its properties on the server side? I initially thought that this approach of **"hidden inputs"** works to pass objects, but even for the `user_profile ` it turns out to be a string too so I cannot access its properties. Do I need to pass each property individually and construct an object on the server side instead?

Comment: Don't want to be rude, but you have to cope with this problem by yourself. I cannot help you here - you don't understand the principle of sending data to forms and types of variables in js (and probably js data transformations). Find some info on [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and  [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/function.json-decode.php) (php side) - if you master both of them, you will be able to clear this out.

Comment: Shortly try to achieve your goal this way: output html form server side > populate html form with simple values inside  inputs (not with objects) > on ajax request append your `user_profile` object (and any other) to data sent to server > make server code to work with your data and return valid data on success. What you're ding wrong - is trying to populate html input with object - it can work this way, but it is not a good way to do it! The better way - is to append additional data main data sent with ajax request.

Comment: I'm working with express, I don't understand PHP. I understand basic principles of data transformation and sending data over the forms. What I don't understand is, even after Stringyfing the value (converting the value into an object) I am still unable to access the properties, getting "undefined" console.logs..
**@ Just read your second comment** - Makes sense, thanks.

Comment: JSON.stringify is NOT "converting the value into an object". It is a reverse process. All forms (server platform independent) send data to server via predefined protocols POST and GET. Those protocols send plain text data. JSON is the protocol that helps sending objects via these protocols. I think that there might be custom developed protocols and standarts which work in some other ways, but there's a little chance that you're working with one of those on your project now...